# Returning Text From A DropDown MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown I am populating with data that looks like....

```
  List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Some Name",
            Value = "1"
        });
```

The dropdown is this

```
 <%: Html.DropDownList("Nick", ViewData["Nick"] as SelectList, new { @onchange = "this.form.submit()" })%>
```

This successfully returns the "Value" property to my action method, I wanna return the "Text" property instead. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'text' isn't returned. It only returns the value by definition (this is HTML that's doing this). You could swap it so that it only returned the text by simply swapping the content inside the value to be "Some Name".

```
 List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
 items.Add(new SelectListItem
 {
    Text = "Some Name",
    Value = "Some Name"
 });
```

More likely, you'll probably find that it's better to simply get the value using the key you get sent back to you. Loosely speaking, something like this pseudo(-esque) code.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel viewModel)
 {
     var listOfOptions = GetListOfOptions(viewModel.Nick);
     string selectedOptionText = listOfOptions.Text;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this it means that you are doing something wrong. Normally the controller which rendered the view containing this dropdown populated `ViewData["Nick"]` (it should have populated a view model instead of ViewData but that's another discussion). So the controller already knows the mapping between the value and the text. So when you postback the value you should be capable of determining the text by the same technique you used before.

Comment: Why this has been downvoted? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, he's going through the same issue I was. Sometimes you have to use `ViewData[]` and other resources because your model contains another object totally different to your `ViewData[]` object and the framework standard code is not so helpful, and sometimes these study cases require customization in the default framework code. Similar to Controller Dependency Injection.