# get value and text from dropdown with .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and want to get the value and text from a dropdown from the view to the controller.

I can get the value like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Appointment appointment)
{                
    var site = Request["siteSelect"];
}
```

But how do I get the Text?

Comment: could you please post the code of your corresponding View? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning Text From A DropDown MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997362/returning-text-from-a-dropdown-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, the text from the dropdown will not be sent when the form is posted to the server.

Check this post:
[Returning Text From A DropDown MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997362/returning-text-from-a-dropdown-mvc?rq=1)